# PHP - Get second column value from primary key on same row

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have two tables in one database.

```
id | title
---------           // table name is tableone
1  |  a
2  |  b
3  |  c
4  |  d
5  |  a
6  |  b
7  |  c
8  |  d
```

for the first table the primary key is the ID column. from this table I am using PHP to create a HTML table which works fine.

The second table

```
id | version
---------
a  |  1
b  |  3
c  |  6
d  |  7
```

in the while loop for the first table I have predefined the title value as

```
$title = $id['title'];
```

within the while loop i am using another while loop yet this time I am trying to use the predefined title to access the matching id's corresponding version row value on the second table using :

```
mysql_query("SELECT version FROM tableone WHERE ID=".$title)
```

however i am hinted with the error

> Unknown column 'a' in 'where clause'

what is the problem and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you can avoid it, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should must enclose the $title in quotes like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT version FROM tableone WHERE ID='".$title."'")
```

If you have user supplied input, you should make sure that your code is secure for all cases.

In this post are some good informations about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714107/php-mysql-security-checklist-the-definitive-practical-guide

Comment: @YusafKhaliq That checklist linked to in this answer is rather out of date now, use this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I'll repeat my comment for you as you didn't mention it in your answer. If you can avoid it, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Hey @vascowhite if you've read my profile description I'm new to php and mysql, this was just self taught practise for me, and i don't fully understand web terminology, but from what ive read and youve commented, are you saying i should learn PDO or MysQLi instead,and which would you personally recommend learning?

Comment: @YusafKhaliq I haven't looked at your profile. I would definitely recommend learning PDO, follow the link in my comment for an easy to follow tutorial. The mysql_ functions will disappear soon so its a waste of time learning them. You'll be glad you put the effort into PDO. Good luck.

Comment: and one more Qs to use MySQLi can i still use the old mysql database on cpanel?

Comment: @YusafKhaliq You don't have to change your database to use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: PDO is your new interface to your mysql database. If the database server updates (it does from time to time), PDO goes together with that. The `mysql_*` functions have stopped with Mysql Server 5.1 which is already some time ago. It's likely you have a newer database server than that. Just for your info so that you can see how outdated that already today is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a separate query within the loop, it's likely to be better to get all the information with one query using a join:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id, title, version
FROM tableone t1
JOIN tabletwo t2 ON t1.title = t2.id
```